# Can spouses filing jointly give gifts to each other and claim the gift exemption?

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax

Is it considered as an exclusion/exemption under the gift tax, if spouses who are both working and filing jointly give gifts to each other even though in reality the amount of the gift still stays with the family?

Comment: Just to clarify, giving money as a 'gift' does not mean that you can exempt it from paying income taxes.  If I earn $50k, and 'give' $25k to my wife, I still owe income tax on $50k.  The normal gift tax situation would be if I gave $25k to a friend, I would owe income tax on $50k, **plus** gift tax on $11k ($25k - $14k annual gift exemption).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both spousal units are US citizens, they have unlimited transfer ability, no gift tax issue.

Comment: "spousal units" .. heh.

Comment: Thx for edit. "they has"? On a personal note, I aced the College math (SAT) exam, 800. English, uh, not.

Comment: Is "gifting" allowed as a tax relief? For example, assuming income tax is 30%, and I make $1000. Instead of giving the government $300, I first apply $900 "gifting", then I will pay the government 30% of the remaining $100 = $30?

Comment: In the US, a personal gift doesn't reduce your tax. Only a gift to a qualified charity, which is then called a "donation."

Answer (score 6):

There would be no point to claim the gift exemption because a gift from a spouse that you file jointly with wouldn't be considered income. It would be the same as if you moved money from one bank account to another.